# Refresh a button

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

 }
```

My application contains a update button. when I click the button the browser must automatically refresh the page.

Is there any code behind code for button?

Answer (score 4):

there is none. Doing so will create a postback on your page, and so will "refresh" your page, at least everything that was done in the page load event and in the prerender event.

In a updatePanel in ajax, it will create a callback. So that only the updatePanel will undergo the postback on the client side, whereas the whole page cycle will be run on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

with server-side button control - you cant.

not sure what are you trying to achieve, but here's a JS workaround for the issue (using JS `location.reload()` to reload the page):

```
<input type="button" value="refresh" onclick="javascript:location.reload()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it

[image]

Comment: you sure, does this force page to `"refresh"`?

Comment: @NikoG. - It hits the breakpoint on Page_Load everytime i click the refresh button.

Comment: ok... add `if (Page.IsPostBack)` on `Page_Load` event and test it youself. I'm quite sure this is postback not "refresh".